# onKeyPress type in Typescript in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have built a calculator app with React & Typescript.
However, the input can only be given by clicking the button with the mouse as of now. I want to change the allow the user to be able to press the number/symbol keys & the calculator should work.

For the I am trying to use the `OnKeyPress` event as below

```
const keyPressEvent = (event: KeyboardEvent, digit: number) => {
    if (Number.isFinite(+event.key) && +event.key === digit) {
      updateCalc(event.key.toString());
    } else {
      return;
    }
  };

  const createDigits = (): JSX.Element[] => {
    const digits = [];
    for (let i: number = 1; i < 10; i++) {
      digits.push(
        <button
          onClick={() => updateCalc(i.toString())}
          onKeyPress={(e) => keyPressEvent(e, i)}
          key={i}
        >
          {i}
        </button>
      );
    }
    return digits;
  };
```

But I get an error message as below

```
[{
    "resource": "/C:/Users/mys2kor/Desktop/web-dev/ccube/src/App.tsx",
    "owner": "typescript",
    "code": "2345",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Argument of type 'KeyboardEvent<HTMLButtonElement>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'KeyboardEvent'.\n  Type 'KeyboardEvent<HTMLButtonElement>' is missing the following properties from type 'KeyboardEvent': isComposing, initKeyboardEvent, DOM_KEY_LOCATION_LEFT, DOM_KEY_LOCATION_NUMPAD, and 14 more.",
    "source": "ts",
    "startLineNumber": 39,
    "startColumn": 44,
    "endLineNumber": 39,
    "endColumn": 45
}]
```

Can anyone help resolving this issue? Thanks.

Comment: Events triggered by react are not real DOM events: they undergo a certain transformation and their types are a bit different. So you need to `import {KeyboardEvent} from 'react'` and use this type instead of browser native `KeyboardEvent`